# App crash on UITableView insertSections: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have pagination where I add new sections to the UITableView in the following way:

```
/* 
Update my datasource by adding required number of new objects to NSMutableArray 
*/
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, totalNewSections)];
[myTableView beginUpdates];
[myTableView insertSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```

The app randomly crashes on line `[ordersTableView endUpdates];` with error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0
>   .. 10]'

Also, I've checked `[self numberOfSectionsInTableView:myTableView]` is same as `startIndex + totalNewSections`. So, no error there.

Edit:
I update my NSMutableArray data source accordingly. It has required number of objects.

Comment: You modified the dataSource of the UI part of the TableView, where do you the same for the dataSource?

Comment: You use a `NSMutableArray` for your dataSource? What's been called to fill your cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Update it also.

Comment: First of all you don't need `beginUpdates / endUpdates` at all in this case but second of all you need to insert the corresponding section in the data source array **before** calling `insertSections`.

Comment: @Larme Yes, I use a NSMutableArray as my dataSource and update it accordingly.
@vadian, Yes, I know, however, it crashes without `beginUpdates / endUpdates` as well. I update my datasource accordingly.

Comment: And where do you update it accordingly exactly?

Comment: @Larme I update it just before inserting new sections.